# remove files from git is difficult

Tags: git

Again and again I follow the instructions but the files are not removed.

```
fatal: pathspec 'build' did not match any files
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git rm --cached -r build/distributions/
fatal: pathspec 'build/distributions/' did not match any files
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git commit -m "refactored"
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
    modified:   .idea/workspace.xml

Untracked files:
    .gitignore
    Effects/
    Textures/
    assets/Textures/3D/
    assets/Textures/BumpMapTest/
    assets/Textures/ColorRamp/
    assets/Textures/ColoredTex/
    assets/Textures/Cursors/
    assets/Textures/HdrTest/
    assets/Textures/Sky/
    assets/Textures/Terrain/
    build/

no changes added to commit
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': montao
Password for 'https://montao@github.com': 
Counting objects: 889, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (844/844), done.
Writing objects: 100% (889/889), 214.55 MiB | 348.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 889 (delta 383), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 0f0c9d2b284114de3032395332d440e1
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File build/distributions/spaceworld.zip is 150.17 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/distributions/spaceworld.tar is 154.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/assets/libs/assets.jar is 149.27 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/assets/libs/assets.jar is 136.69 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/montao/spaceworld.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/montao/spaceworld.git'
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git rm -r --cached build
fatal: pathspec 'build' did not match any files
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> ls build
assets/  classes/  dependency-cache/  distributions/  libs/  scripts/  tmp/
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld>
```

I committed too many files and git makes it difficult to remove them. What can I do?

I try again follow the instructions and the same error appears.

```
M   .idea/workspace.xml
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git rm --cached -r build/distributions/
fatal: pathspec 'build/distributions/' did not match any files
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git commit -m "refactored"
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
    modified:   .idea/workspace.xml

Untracked files:
    .gitignore
    Effects/
    Textures/
    assets/Textures/3D/
    assets/Textures/BumpMapTest/
    assets/Textures/ColorRamp/
    assets/Textures/ColoredTex/
    assets/Textures/Cursors/
    assets/Textures/HdrTest/
    assets/Textures/Sky/
    assets/Textures/Terrain/

no changes added to commit
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld> git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': montao
Password for 'https://montao@github.com': 
Counting objects: 889, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (844/844), done.
Writing objects: 100% (889/889), 214.55 MiB | 922.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 889 (delta 383), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: d05f62b01f57f07531635f28bda11733
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File build/distributions/spaceworld.zip is 150.17 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/distributions/spaceworld.tar is 154.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/assets/libs/assets.jar is 149.27 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/assets/libs/assets.jar is 136.69 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/montao/spaceworld.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/montao/spaceworld.git'
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/spaceworld>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Untracking `build` dir? If so, it is untracked.

Comment: @Blackus But when I try `git push` it is complaining about the `build` dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.sql'
```

Note: Replace *.sql with your file name or file type. Be very careful because this will go through every commit and rip this file type out.

Comment: I get `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`

Comment: Then you have files that you haven't committed. I think, instead of downvoting everything that doesn't immediately work, you need to back up and address a few other problems.

First, are you on a new branch or anything? Are you doing this from the master branch? Have you pushed these files to the repo or anything?

What's stopping you from just deleting your current setup, and init the repo again and by pulling down a fresh copy?

Comment: Shouldn't this be trivial? I'm stuck here for hours and all I want is to delete files. It feels like idiot savant when I can write the program but I can't use git.

Comment: Trust me, I have been there. Git takes some time to get used to. You might invest in a GUI program so you can see the Git branches and files a little easier. 

Here is what I would do: I'd create a new branch and checkout that new branch. Then I'd commit all of my current changes to that new branch. Then I'd try running that script that I paste in my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

A one-line command once it's installed:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M spaceworld.git
```

I'd also stash changes or rebase from master before running it.

Comment: It feels like idiot savant if I must install a program just to remove a file

Comment: Maybe so, but this handles all sorts of history and cache pruning automatically with a single line.

Comment: Also FYI, it's usually bad taste to downvote every answer just because they don't work for you. They may work for others. Save downvoting for incorrect or simply bad answers.

Comment: ^ I agree with brandonscript. Don't downvote everything as soon as it doesn't work for you. Otherwise, no one will help you. I assure you, the solutions that we're posting work for other cases.

Comment: I'm trying to say that this should be TRIVIAL. All I want is remove a file.

Comment: git isn't trivial 